# Google authenticator iOS app crash / fails to load after iOS 14.2 update

Tags: ios, google, two-factor-authentication

When I tap the app, it immediately crashes. I don't want to delete and reinstall the app because I am scared to lose my tokens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to reinstall the application without deleting it:

1. Go to Settings > iPhone Storage
2. Find Authenticator
3. Tap "Offload App"
4. After the process tap "Re-install App"

This provides to remove and install the application part, not your data/tokens. Your data remains.

I tried and succeeded on iPhone XS iOS 14.2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure that you always have a backup of your 2FA accounts, I would suggest the use of [Authy](https://authy.com/)

It also enable you to have 2FA accounts across other devices - e.g. iPhone, iPad, Mac, Android, Linus and Windows - they are always in sync, and if you get a new device, you just login, and you are up and running.